# How to refer to an estimate value from the regression output in rmakrdown document using back quote?

Tags: r-markdown

I know how to refer to the numeric value from r stat analysis in my rmarkdown document, for example, putting `r round(x.peaks[,2],3)[1]` between the **back quotes** without having to update whenever the value changes. But I was wondering if there's a way to do the same for the value of estimated coefficient from regression output. So for example, I want to put the intercept -0.32958 (please see the table) in my rmarkdown document using back quotes without having to type or update every time it generates a different output depending on dataset.

```
lm(formula = log(p_share) ~ xxx, data = df2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.04165 -0.37272 -0.00279  0.48895  1.16493 

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        -0.32958    0.05525  -5.965 1.62e-08 ***
xxx             0.03313    0.11835   0.280     0.78    
  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6103 on 154 degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.0005087, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.005981 
F-statistic: 0.07838 on 1 and 154 DF,  p-value: 0.7799
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use package `broom`.

**An example:**

````
title: "Untitled"
header-includes:    
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r}

library(broom)

#our data
df = data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))

#our model
model <- lm(y ~ x, data=df)

t_tab <- tidy(model)

t_tab
```

Your coef is `r round(t_tab$estimate[1],3)`
````

[image]